# Зоны ответственности View и ViewModel. Android+Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

Начинаю осваивать MVVM, есть вопросы. Никак не могу прочно усвоить зоны ответственности View и ViewModel.

Согласно паттерну MVVM в моем проекте "модель"-репозиторий - класс некоторого устройства, объединяющего в себе несколько однотипных модулей (аппаратных устройств), т.е. объектов одного типа (класса).
Каждый модуль имеет свои параметры.
Модули различаются адресом (идентификатором). Теоретически заранее неизвестно сколько модулей подключено к устройству.
Задача - реализовать процедуру настройки каждого отдельного модуля.
Очевидно, что настроечный экран (Fragment) на каждый отдельный модуль делать бессмысленно.
Как реализовать идентификацию модуля из фрагмента и как правильно обеспечить доступ к параметрам модуля?

В данный момент мысли таковы:
При переключении во фрагмент настроек я знаю какой модуль буду настраивать. Т.е. при создании фрагмента могу адрес передать во фрагмент через Bundle.

В листенере ввода параметра (внутри фрагмента) получаю ссылку на конкретный модуль и далее нужный параметр устанавливаю в соответствии с введенным числом в окне ввода.

viewModel.getModule(addr)?.parameter = ....

Насколько такой подход противоречит паттерну MVVM?
Меня смущает почти прямой доступ к полю класса репозитория изнутри View.

Уточнение по сохранению параметра модуля:

```
(viewModel.getModuleByAddr(0x02) as PowerUnit).controlFolder.relay1 = 1
```

Здесь 0x02 - адрес модуля,
PowerUnit - класс модуля (на самом деле там разнотипные модули, наследованные от общего предка).
Так вот, беспокоит необходимость импорта класса PowerUnit внутри фрагмента. По-моему, это неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, почитав ликбезы, решил что это неправильный подход. Во View все должно быть "тупо", без лишних алгоритмов и типов данных. Получается, я пытался работать из View с объектами репозитория почти в обход viewModel.

Сейчас решил сделать иначе: все параметры теперь обернуты классом:

```
data class Param<T> (
val idTag: String,
val parValue: T,
val updateEnable: Boolean = true
```

)

Соответственно идентификация параметра из View - через idTag, что-то вроде этого:
viewModel.setModuleParameter(moduleAddr = 0x02, "relay1", parameterValue = 1)

Соответственно, параметр устанавливается по правильной цепочке View->ViewModel->Device->Module->Param.
Громоздко, конечно, в плане поиска нужного параметра по тегу, но зато никаких лишних импортов в View.